# How to avoid boilerplate code constructors?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Let's have class like this:

```
struct Base {
  Base() { ... }
  Base(int) { ... }
  Base(int,string) { ... }
  ...
};
```

I'd like to inherit many classes from `Base`, so I write

```
struct Son : public Base {
  Son() : Base() { }
  Son(int) : Base(int) { }
  Son(int,string) : Base(int,string) { }
};

struct Daughter : public Base {
  Daughter() : Base() { }
  Daughter(int) : Base(int) { }
  Daughter(int,string) : Base(int,string) { }
};
```

and I don't need to add any code to child's constructors. Is it possible to inherit them implicitly? To call them the same way like in `Base`, just change the name? Preprocessor can be abused here, but is there any other workaround?

Comment: C++11 has delegating constructors.

Comment: Wild suggestion: could you consider adding some (carefully selected) default arguments ? `Daughter(int i = 0, string s = "Hello"): Base(i, s)` would be a single constructor.

Comment: @111111: Great! Could you please give me a link or example?

Comment: @111111: different usage, delegating constructors are about `Base()` calling `Base(int)`, not about inheriting them in derived classes.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Not in this case - I need to call constructors corresponding to Base class

Comment: @JanTuroň I hope this helps I didn't post it as an answer because I am not entirely sure it is your use case (you can decide) nor can I remember if most compilers support it yet. If it meets you need and your compiler supports it then it will make things a lot cleaner: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#delegating-ctor

Comment: @JanTuroň: which is why I indicated to 111111 that delegating constructors did not seem useful for you.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Right, I was too hasty. But still, it is good point to start with.

Comment: @JanTuroň, not an answer to your question. but i'd argue that you should take a look at your design. Derived class `is a` base class with some special part. Both the base class part and derived class part needs to be constructed by user supplied parameters. If your derived class has no special part that needs to be constructed then are they really sub-classes? if the special parts are only methods then should you not use `strategy` instead of `inheritance`?

Comment: @Vikas: good point: I'd like to have something like mixin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a C++11 compliant compiler (§12.9 in the standard), you can actually do this quite easily:

```
struct Son : public Base {
  using Base::Base;
};
```

This inherits all constructors from `Base` and is equivalent to your code for class `Son`.

Comment: The latest versions of at least VStudio and GCC implement many C++11 features. This looks simple to implement, so I would bet they do, but don't really know for sure.

Comment: Looks like `(GCC) 4.7.0 20111203 (experimental)` doesn't

Comment: Indeed, according to their own website (http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) it does not.

Comment: I'm updating my answer to reflect the fact that, unfortunately, current compilers don't yet support this features.

Comment: clang implements delegating constructors, but not inheriting them. See http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html for details.

Comment: @TobiasLangner Same as GCC. I would have thought that inheriting constructors would be easier to implement, but I must be missing something.

Comment: IAR EWARM 6.4 doesn't implement this :(